# HTML5 Chrome checkValidity onBlur

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, validation

I'm trying to do a simple checkValidity of a numeric input field on blur, but can't get it to work properly. Does this work in Chrome yet? For instance:

```
<input onBlur="checkValidity()" type="number" name="x" id="x" min="64" max="2048" value=64>
```

or

```
<input onBlur="this.checkValidity()" type="number" name="x" id="x" min="64" max="2048" value=64>
```

Don't seem to do anything. However, in the console,

```
$("#x")[0].checkValidity()
```

does return true or false based on the current value in the input box and the limits above of (64,2048). Is this broken, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: You mentioned this yourself: "`checkValidity()` does **return true or false**", so it seems that the method _returns a value_ that tells your script whether it's valid or not, instead of actually do something (e.g. hinting user, blocking input, etc.). So your `onblur` event handler actually "works", it just doesn't do UI-things.

Comment: yeah, its not throwing an error. When I actually submit the form, the validation does work and there are popups where there are bad inputs. THose are what I was going for onBlur...

Comment: I _guess_ you want to trigger the validate popup whenever the user "finishes" an input? That's not possible, as that's browser's behavior, not a HTML spec. You can use `if(!obj.checkValidity()){...}` to somehow "emulate" the behavior.

Comment: Yeah, thats kinda what I'm going for here. After the user inputs an invalid number into the field above and blurs out to the next field, alert them to the error before they actually go to submit and might have multiple errors.

Comment: Seems like there's no way to get the browser default action (when checkValidity() fails) to fire unless you do a full submit.  That's kind of a shame.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a demonstration of what you may want to head to:

http://jsfiddle.net/9gSZS/

```
<input type="number" min="64" max="256" onblur="validate(this);" />
```

```js
function validate(obj)
{
  if(!obj.checkValidity())
  {
    alert("You have invalid input. Correct it!");
    obj.focus();
  }
}
```

Noted that I'm just **demonstrating** the *concept* here; `alert` may cause very **unpleasant** experience, so don't just copy it.

Use some floating DIV to attract your user, instead of the full-blocking `alert`.

Answer (score 11):

I realize this question is *many* years old at this point but if anyone else comes across it, the correct way to achieve the behavior that OP wanted appears to be to use `onblur="reportValidity()"` instead `onblur="checkValidity"`.

Comment: You deserve a gold medal

Answer (score 0):

You should use onChange Event

for example

```
var input1 = document.getElementById('txt_username');
    input1.onchange = function(){
        input1.setCustomValidity(input1.validity.patternMismatch ? 'username must match a-z,A-Z,0-9,4-16 character' : ''); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution

```
$("form").focusout(function(){
        if(!$("form")[0].checkValidity()){
            setTimeout(function(){$(":submit").eq(0).trigger('click');},0);
        }
    });
```

If any of your form elements lose focus you check the form validity. If the form is invalid have jquery click the first submit button. Have to use a timeout for some reason to get it to work. A timeout of zero just moves the function to the end of the queue of functions.

Answer (score -2):

`onblur="checkValidity()"` has no effect because `blur` event is not cancelable.