# Fire html5 email validator on losing focus besides just on submission of forms

Tags: html, email-validation

I have an email input field where i check if the email is already present in my database using ajax on losing focus from that email input. I want to make sure the email entered is in the correct format before i make an ajax call. Can i do this with html5 built-in email validator or do i have to write my own validation function?

Edit:I am already using the html5 email validator but it validates the email only when the form is submitted.

Comment: It should validate automatically with every key press...you're using `<input type="email"` right?

Comment: @MattBrowne `<input id="email1" name="email1" required="required" type="email" placeholder="Your email address" onblur="checkEmailAvailability();" />`   `checkEmailAvailability()` is the ajax function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Firefox**, it should check the email for validity as you're typing by default (native HTML5 behavior):
http://jsfiddle.net/xs65r/

But to support all HTML5 browsers, you'll need to manually call `checkValidity()` `onblur` and/or `onkeydown`.

See this link for more detail:
[HTML5 Chrome checkValidity onBlur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351260/html5-chrome-checkvalidity-onblur)

As you said in your comment below, you have to use the function this.checkValidity() in an if clause in your onblur function before making the ajax call, and dispay any errors yourself, since in browsers other than Firefox the native validation message UI isn't triggered unless the form is submitted.

Comment: i know for a fact that it doesn't validate email as you type as i use email input type for login with no `onblur` or any other function and there too the validator only kicks in when the form the submitted.

Comment: It must be something else in your code then (or maybe your browser) because the jsfiddle works as I described.

Comment: i have tested it both on `Chrome Version 26.0.1410.64` and `Internet Explorer version 10.0.9200.16540`. It only shows the invalid email message when the the submit button is clicked.

Comment: My apologies; I thought I recollected that other browsers behaved the same way as Firefox for this but I was mistaken. This should help clear things up: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351260/html5-chrome-checkvalidity-onblur

Comment: ty that helped. I only have to use the function `checkValidity(this)` in an if clause in my onblur function before making the ajax call.

Comment: hey `checkValidity(this)` wont actually work it should be `obj.checkValidity()` where obj is the parameter `this` passed to the function. Also, i just found out there's no way to trigger the native browser UI for validation unless you call the submit() which basically submits the form. But you can still use the native validator without the UI through checkValidity().

Comment: That sucks...well fortunately there are validation libraries available that understand HTML5 and will position validation messages for you, like [jQuery Tools validator](http://jquerytools.org/demos/validator) and [parseley.js](http://parsleyjs.org). But I think the native UI in most HTML5 browsers looks better so it's too bad you can't trigger it for HTML5 browsers.